# What does "overstates the case" mean?

Tags: meaning

In [Runaway Jury (2003)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runaway_Jury), during voir dire process of mass shootings case, defendant's lawyer Cable and
plaintiff's attorney Rohr accept Ms. Deets as a jury member:

> Cable: We accept this juror.

Then a camera focuses on a young female juror in the jury pool:

> Jury #1: Having an AK-47 **overstates the case**.

Then scene suddenly cuts to the room where defendant's jury consultant Rankin Fitch
and his team, who are leading defense attorney Durwood Cable through a microphone:

> Rankin Fitch: I want her. Yes, I want her.

Scene cuts back to court room, where Cable accept this young female juror:

> Cable: No objection, Your Honor.

What does "overstates the case" mean?

Comment: You'll find the phrase in a dictionary: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/overstate-the-case

Comment: @Astralbee  Those are example phrases and it doesn't explain the meaning, **which I am seeking**.

Comment: I agree with OP, the meaning of the idiom is not as readily available on searches as one might think...

Comment: What was the jury member responding to. Had she been asked a question by Cable or Rohr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scene in the film is where jurors are being chosen. IN US prosecution courts, a pool of jurors is offered and, before the trial begins, the prosecution and defence can remove any that they feel may be prejudiced in the case.

In the scene, the jurors are being asked what they think about *gun control*. In the USA, it is a citizen's right to keep a gun for defence, although not everybody agrees with this law and the ideology against it is called 'gun control'. As anyone who believes in gun control may be prejudicial against the shooter, the defence would not want them, but the prosecution would.

> -What about gun control?
> -Same way I feel about birth control, man. It doesn't work.
> -We accept this juror.

To "overstate a case" means *to go too far*, or *to go beyond what is necessary*. So, saying that an AK47 (a heavy assault rifle) "overstates the case" means that owning this kind of weapon goes way beyond the principle behind the right to bear arms. This kind of weapon is not just for protection, it is for attack. So, this person would be useful to the prosecution because they believe that while guns may be lawful, there should be a limit to the *kind* of gun owned.

Answer (score 1):

To overstate a case is basically [to exaggerate something](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/overstate_the_case.html).

We can think of the [verb state](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/state) which means "to express something in words" and adding the [adjective "over"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/over) in its "excessive" sense.

Basically, it's saying that having such a weapon is an exaggeration.

Unless there's an specific law related meaning of the idiom, to which I admit ignorance.

Comment: exaggerate means makes the case popular in this context??

Comment: I haven't seen the movie, but my interpretation of the scene you describe is more along the lines of "having an AK-47 is an exaggeration, a kitchen knife would have been enough".

Similar to the "use a sledgehammer to crack a nut" idiom. Using such a hammer to crack a nut is overstating the case.